# Express get method not calling first function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemailer

So I am writing some code to send me a email when someone visits my website. Here is the code I have

```js
app.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  var mailOptions = {
    from: 'removed for obvious reasons',
    to: 'removed for obvious reasons',
    subject: 'User visited',
    text: 'A user has visited your site'
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    }
  });
  console.log("User visited");
  next();
}, function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile( path.join( __dirname, "client-files", "index.html" ));
});
```

But when I visit my website then I get nothing. I don't get a email and nothing's printed out, I just get the web page. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you getting `"User visited"`? Or literally nothing?

Comment: @ChrisG Literally nothing

Comment: Try moving `next()` into the callback you're passing to `sendMail()`. That function is async, so that code will immediately move on to the 2nd handler right now.

Comment: @ChrisG Still nothing

Comment: `await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){`

Comment: sidenote, use a task queue for sendMail, never send emails inline with the request its slow and prone to failure or botting abuse

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is async code. In short: The order of the code is not the order it gets executed.

It takes time to send that mail. NodeJS is single-threaded it sends the email and then continues on with the code.

So it sends the email and calls next function right away and sends the user to the next handler, without knowing anything about the email.

I can't find a real good reason to have two different handlers.

**Version 1: Don't wait for email, send the page right away**

```js
app.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  var mailOptions = {
    from: 'removed for obvious reasons',
    to: 'removed for obvious reasons',
    subject: 'User visited',
    text: 'A user has visited your site'
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    }
  });

  console.log("User visited");

  res.sendFile( path.join( __dirname, "client-files", "index.html" ));
});
```

Result: It will

1. Log out 'user visited'
2. Send file page
3. Send email
4. Log out 'Email sent'

**Version 2: Wait for email**

```js
app.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  var mailOptions = {
    from: 'removed for obvious reasons',
    to: 'removed for obvious reasons',
    subject: 'User visited',
    text: 'A user has visited your site'
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
      console.log("User visited");
      res.sendFile( path.join( __dirname, "client-files", "index.html" ));
    }
  });
});
```

Result: It will

1. Send email
2. Log out 'Email sent'
3. Log out 'User visited'
4. Send file

Comment: I tried this but none of the code is running at all except for the res.sendFile. I even tried removing the email thing and just had a log statement and the sendFile and it didn't print anything but still sent the website.